# Bash script to remove redundant lines

Tags: bash

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to make a bash script that cleans out some data output files.  The files look like this:

```
/path/
/path/to
/path/to/keep
/another/
/another/path/
/another/path/to
/another/path/to/keep
```

I'd like to end up with this:

```
/path/to/keep
/another/path/to/keep
```

I want to cycle through lines of the file, checking the next line to see if it contains the current line, and if so, delete the current line from the file.  Here's my code:

```
for LINE in $(cat bbutters_data2.txt)
do
    grep -A1 ${LINE} bbutters_data2.txt
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
       sed -i '/${LINE}/d' ./bbutters_data2.txt
    fi
done
```

Comment: What does your code produce? Do you have a question?

Comment: Are your lines definitely sorted neatly like that?

Comment: wondering if this is an output of a `du`.

Comment: That looks an awful lot like `find` output. If it is, and your end nodes are files, try adding a `-type f` to the find command to get only directories.

Comment: @Daenyth: I'm pretty sure you mean "to only get files" but this is still great advice.

Comment: That's what I meant... somehow got it reversed :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your input file is sorted in the way that you have shown:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && substr($0,1,length(last))!=last {print last;} {last=$0;} END{print last}' file
/path/to/keep
/another/path/to/keep
```

#### How it works

awk reads through the input file line by line.  Every time we read a new line, we compare it to the last.  If the new line does not contain the last line, then we print the last line.  In more detail:

- `NR>1 && substr($0,1,length(last))!=last {print last;}`

  If this is not the first line and if the last line, called `last`, is not contained in the current line, `$0`, then print the last line.
- `last=$0`

  Update the variable `last` to the current line.
- `END{print last}`

  After we finish reading the file, print the last line.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes.  Explanation added.

Answer (score -1):

I like the `awk` solution, but bash itself can handle the task. **Note:** the solution (both `awk` and `bash`), require that the lesser included paths be listed in increasing order. Here is an alternative bash solution (bash only due to the glob match operation):

```
#!/bin/bash

fn="${1:-/dev/stdin}"   ## accept filename or stdin

[ -r "$fn" ] || {       ## validate file is readable
    printf "error: file not found: '%s'\n" "$fn"
    exit 1
}

declare -i cnt=0        ## flag for 1st iteration

while read -r line; do  ## for each line in file

    ## if 1st iteration, fill 'last', increment 'cnt', continue
    [ $cnt -eq 0 ] && { last="$line"; ((cnt++)); continue; }

    ## while 'line' is a child of 'last', continue, else print
    [[ $line = "${last%/}"/* ]] || printf "%s\n" "$last"

    last="$line"        ## update last=$line
done <"$fn"

[ ${#line} -eq 0 ] &&   ## print last line (updated for non POSIX line end)
    printf "%s\n" "$last" || 
    printf "%s\n" "$line"

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash path_uniql.sh < dat/incpaths.txt
/path/to/keep
/another/path/to/keep
```

Comment: Another cowardly downvote from someone lacking the integrity to comment.

Comment: Downvote for treating filenames as code. Mainly with `[[ ! $line =~ $last ]]`. Consider a filename containing `.` in its name. `[[ $line != "$last"* ]]` is the test you really want there. I also recommend not using `[` in bash, use the superior `[[...]]` for testing strings and files, and `((...))` for testing integers instead.

Comment: In my opinion the syntax of bash's testing is impressively bad even when you use it correctly, and this somehow manages to be even less readable than that.  That's another valid place where the downvote came from. It's not mine though.

Comment: Though it's not mentioned in the question, it would be interesting to compare performance on a sizeable data-set. I did something similar a few years ago and found awk to be several orders of magnitude faster than pure bash.

Comment: I added my downvote for my own reason and because @geirha is correct that this will produce incorrect output if the list it's processing happens to include any regular expression notation.

Comment: @geirha with all due respect, **have you tried your proposed solution?** It doesn't work. While you may prefer `[[`, you automatically make your scripts **non-POSIX compliant** with its use. It should be used only in the limited circumstances where a POSIX solution is unavailable. Instead of downvoting because something differs from your "opinion", why don't you "man up" and submit a proposed solution of your own. It is far easier to hide behind a downvote than it is to throw your hat into the ring and put your solution out for comment.

Comment: @Wug - you **"invent your own requirements, and then downvote because a solution doesn't meet it?"** You are way out of line. SO deserves better.

Comment: @Component10, thank you for your positive contribution to the discussion. I too have tested, not this script, but have found similar results with both `awk` and `sed` being generally faster by an order of magnitude. I'll cook up a dataset and if the results are different than expected, I'll update with the results.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `last=/path/to line=/path/to/keep; [[ $line = "$last"* ]]; echo $?` and `last=/path/t. line=/path/to/keep; [[ $line = "$last"* ]]; echo $?` outputs 0 and 1 respectively. Seems to be working. As for sticking with `sh` syntax in `bash`; it's a bit like sticking with **C** syntax in a **C++** program ... because maybe you'll change your mind and go back to **C** ..? If you're writing a bash script, why not use bash syntax? Makes it more consistent.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Run your script with the following input: "/.........\n/INCORRECT/OUTPUT". I'm not inventing requirements. The asker of this question mentioned nowhere that he wants regular expression comparisons, and given that he's comparing things that look like filenames, it's reasonable to assume that he doesn't. `=~` is the regular expression comparison operator, not (as you claim) the substring operator.

Comment: Do you see that path as part of the question? Really? Yes, there will always be corner cases that aren't covered, but can be with additional tests, etc.  @geirha, [**the following may interest you:**](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/57918)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ok, so Linus is not fond of C++, I take it you're not either, and I am not fond of C++ either. That's beside the point. The unwillingness to use bash syntax in a bash script is only secondary, not why I downvoted. Whenever I see someone treat data as code, I downvote outright. And if it's possible to explain the reason within the length of a SE-comment, I do so. It often takes time to comment because people get real offended if I point out problems using the "wrong words". So again I fail.

Comment: I appreciate your follow up. What I don't understand, and may just be a semantics issue, is **treat data as code**? I don't get the point there. I compare a variable `$line` to `$last` (which is the previous `$line`), so I do not understand what you are saying is incorrect with that?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, `[[ string =~ regex ]]`. You're treating the previous line as a regular expression that should match the current line, meaning that any characters that are special in (extended) regular expressions, (like `.`, `()`, `[]`, `?` and `+`) may change the outcome of the test.

Comment: Are you saying that **a string is not a valid regular expression?** The use of `=~` to check for a substring is a **100%** valid use of the operator and does not constitute using data as code. Don't take my word for it. Have you read `man bash`? **"the string to the right of the operator is  considered  an  extended  regular  expression"** There is no limitation on what you put in the string. A downvote on that basis **is just flat wrong**. You are entitled to your own opinion, that's fine, **but you are not entitled to invent new bash restrictions.** That's just nuts.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin (you forgot to highlight me). The following will output "match":  `a="foobar" b="foo"; [[ $a =~ $b ]] && echo match`. The following will **not** output "match": `a="foo(bar)" b="foo("; [[ $a =~ $b ]] && echo match`. In both cases, $b is a substring of $a, but the test give different results. Do you understand why?